# Add range time by query log Grafana

Tags: grafana, grafana-loki

I've been work on Loki for centralized logging with Grafana. I want to 'Explore' log by query without using time control on top of the Grafana. I wonder if its possible to add range time manually by query (not the time control provided by grafana)?

It's probably like

```
{job=docker-container} |~ "error" | startsAt = formatTime | endsAt = formatTime
```

I didn't found any variables that can describe control time range though, also for the labels
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can always setup the date and time in the top right hand side of Grafana and click on "**Apply time range**" as the below image:

[image]